# Some (valid) tags not being returned [OutlineGroupNode is not supported ]

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

The OneNote API is not returning supported tags in some lists.

It seems to be an issue with complex bulleted lists; we just see `OutlineGroupNode is not supported` in the returned markup.

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-note-tags) give some guidelines on how to write out tags to lists, but there's no mention of the API not returning any supported tags in certain situations.

Please see the below example, what rules is this list breaking?

What constitutes an OutlineGroupNode?

Some clarity over what *pre-existing* list/tag content is supported would be appreciated please.

Thanks

[image: A complex hierarchy of tags]

The resulting markup is:

```
<snip>

<!-- OutlineGroupNode is not supported --><br>

<ul>
  <li>
    <p lang="en-GB" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt">
    Top level no tag</p>

    <ul>
      <li style="list-style-type:circle"><span lang="en-GB"
      data-tag="to-do">Sub level with tag</span></li>

      <li style="list-style-type:circle"><span lang="en-GB">Sub
      level no tag</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li style="list-style: none"><br></li>
</ul>

</snip>
```

Answer (score 1):

4 days later it now works; no code changes on my part.

The complex list is returned correctly. No HTML comment in the markup mentioning OutlineGroupNode.

I can only assume that something has changed under the API hood.