# OutlineGroupNode is not supported

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

This list:
[image]

gets returned as this from the api:

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:384px;top:475px;width:624px">
<!-- OutlineGroupNode is not supported -->
<br></div>
```

What is the definition of an OutlineGroup?

Comment: On Windows Desktop clients and older versions of OneNote, the OutlineGroup node is used as an abstract container for holding complex outlines.

Comment: OK, thanks. So, this doesn't look to be a particularly complicated outline. I [found another example previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399430/some-valid-tags-not-being-returned-outlinegroupnode-is-not-supported/37501408#37501408) that you appeared to fix within a few days, is this an example of something you might fix? Or how do I communicate to my users that their content is not supported. It's all feeling a bit vague currently

Comment: I can't promise whether we will fix this particular issue quickly. We typically direct API users to voice their feedback on UserVoice and try to pick top requested items and include them in our backlog/planning process. But right now, we're pretty heads down on other priorities.

In addition to OutlineGroups, there are also other content like Ink that the GET pages/{id}/content API cannot return. For these cases, you can choose to either not display anything to the user or show a warning indicating not all content was fetchable and redirect them to OneNote via onenoteClientUrl /onenoteWebUrl

Answer (score 0):

We've addressed this issue - it should be fixed for you and you should be able to see this content now.